# Fastest way remove certain values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array looking like this :

```
const data =  [
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '04b073133c7843248a7a3dbc968f75a0', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '4420cc109ec54214b68edc906b18e44a', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.75, 0.67, 5.58, 0.5625, 0.129375, 0.691875, 4.185, 0.96255, 5.14755, 0.5025, 0.115575, 0.618075],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '90a7cbf1cf4e4043889626c4119d4b4d', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1232113, 1232133, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

What I want to achieve(but don't know how) is to delete all entries(in the fastest way) that look like the last one in this array, e.g. `[Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017, SKYSCANNER, 0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b, network1, affiliate, 1232113, 1232133, , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Basically, if all values after the 8th position are zeroes the entry is not needed and must be removed.

Typically in my case such array can have between 5-15k entries, so I was wondering what is the fastest way to achieve this? Can someone provide a working snippet?

Thanks!

Comment: "Fastest" will depend on specifics. Make a few variations and run a benchmark.

Comment: Have you checked if any simple filter method is slow at all?

Comment: @Yoshi, yes, but I didn't know how to apply it.

Comment: Is the length of each inner array the same?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli  yes, this length is always the same

Comment: Please add your input data in a way that is actually copy-able and valid javascript. Currently it's really bothersome to use what you've posted.

Comment: @Yoshi, just edited the question. Hope it is better now.

Comment: @RobertRoss That's not a valid array.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia it is.

Comment: Just use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). 15k entries really isn't significant for JS:  `.filter(e => e[7] || e[8] || e[9] || e[10] (etc)....)` Since only one of the properties has to be "truthy" for the row to pass, you can just "or" the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want fast code, just check for the separate values.

The or (`||`) will short-circuit, so the first entry from `e[7]`-`e[18]` that has an value will make the row pass the test, meaning the `filter` will move on to the next row.

```js
const data =  [
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '04b073133c7843248a7a3dbc968f75a0', 'network1', 'affiliate', 1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '4420cc109ec54214b68edc906b18e44a', 'network1', 'affiliate', 1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.75, 0.67, 5.58, 0.5625, 0.129375, 0.691875, 4.185, 0.96255, 5.14755, 0.5025, 0.115575, 0.618075],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '90a7cbf1cf4e4043889626c4119d4b4d', 'network1', 'affiliate', 1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b', 'network1', 'affiliate', 1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b', 'network1', 'affiliate', 1232113, 1232133, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

let test = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i += 1) {
    test = test.concat(data);
}

const start = performance.now();

const result = test.filter(e => e[7]||e[8]||e[9]||e[10]||e[11]||e[12]||e[13]||e[14]||e[15]||e[16]||e[17]||e[18]);

console.log(performance.now() - start);
```

(Timing code borrowed from Yoshi's answer)

(For me,) This runs twice as fast as the `slice` / `every` combination Yoshi used, but half as readable / maintainable.

It's up to you whether you prefer readable code, or if you want to throw all guidelines out of the window to go for *raw speed*.

Answer (score 2):

The following takes 11ms on my age old machine. As Cerbrus writes, just use filter, 15k is not much:

```js
const data = [
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '04b073133c7843248a7a3dbc968f75a0', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '4420cc109ec54214b68edc906b18e44a', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.75, 0.67, 5.58, 0.5625, 0.129375, 0.691875, 4.185, 0.96255, 5.14755, 0.5025, 0.115575, 0.618075],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '90a7cbf1cf4e4043889626c4119d4b4d', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1141338.0, 18164.0, 0.08, 0.07, 0.62, 0.06, 0.0138, 0.0738, 0.465, 0.10695, 0.57195, 0.0525, 0.012075, 0.064575],
    ['Wed Sep 20 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017', 'SKYSCANNER', '0f04f1ff385541d3a8d9ea2f0d85482b', 'network1', 'affiliate',
        1232113, 1232133, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

let test = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i += 1) {
    test = test.concat(data);
}

const start = performance.now();

const result = test.filter(
               // reject entry, if not 
                      // every value from 8th to last
                                              // is 0
    (entry) => !entry.slice(8).every((val) => 0 === val)
);

console.log(performance.now() - start);
```